# Would it be a good practice to store a 'validness' state for movable objects?

Tags: c++

I am designing a library, many of the classes are movable. Many of the movable classes are passed as arguments to functions of other classes. I am thinking how to minimize code for validation checks. The instances of the movable classes are always in a valid state after constructing, however they become invalid after being moved from.

Would it be a good practise to have a flag 'valid' that is true after constructing and becomes false after moving. The only way the object could get valid again is when a valid object is moved into it.

I'll also mention that after moving the objects do not go in a state where calling functions on them would cause undefined behavior or anything. It's just that after moving the contents are garbage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SHOULD I, OR SHOULDN'T I?**

Such a flag might be suitable for debugging purposes, but normally it's up to the developer that is using your *library/code* to make sure that he/she never uses your objects in a way that is quirky after they have been used from.

The whole purpose of *move-constructors* and *move-assignments* is to move the data from `src` to `dst`, which effectively makes `src` contain nothing but garbage, and a developer using such functionality should be aware of this.

<sup>**Note:** constructs that should never be ill-formed includes the assignment operator(s), one should always be able to assign new data to a *moved-from* object.</sup>

---

Since a *move* from an object accessed via a variable (ie. an *lvalue*) only happens if the developer explicitly says so <sup>1)</sup> the developer has with such code signed an invisible contract that renders him/her responsible for any side-effects of using the object after being moved from.

<sup>**Note:** 1)  via `std::move (val)`, `static_cast<T&&> (val)`, or equivalent.</sup>

---

---

**THE STANDARD LIBRARY**

If we look in the Standard library we see that there is no `valid` flag in practice, instead it is (as said) up to the developer to make sure that he doesn't use invalid constructs on a moved-from object.

Comment: It is also good practice to leave the moved-from objects in a self-consistent state (e.g. maintaining invariants) such that it can be used without invoking UB.)

Comment: @juanchopanza if the requirement of a certain member function is that the object contains usable data (ie. valid from the destructors perspective, but garbage) it should be entirely up to the user to make sure such member functions are not invoked. this is how the standard library does it, btw.

Comment: Sure, but the invariants must be maintained. So, with a container, `empty`, `size`, `capacity` etc. have to be consistent with each other.

Comment: @juanchopanza agreed.

Comment: as an example, efficient move-based swapping requires that an object remains move-assignable after being moved from.